# Dict or DataFrame into excel matching keys and columns title

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, dictionary, key

I want to add dictionaries or dataframes to excel based on the keys of the dict

```
dict1={'fruit':'apple','animal':'tiger'}
dict2={'fruit':['banana','mango'],'city':['Rio','Porto']}
```

to excel:

| fruit | animal | city |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple | tiger |  |
| banana |  | rio |
| mango |  | porto |

without the keys if possible. If a key is not on the excel, it creates a new column.
What would be a fast way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict`:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict1, orient='index').T,
           pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict2, orient='index').T],
          ignore_index=True).to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I find it a bit strange to have to use orient='index' and transpose it right after. But putting orient='columns' returns an error. Also, would the pd.join() function work here?

Comment: `join` can't work here because it's based on index and your 2 dataframes have (or should) not have common index

Comment: With `orient='index'`, you can use scalar values as input (your first dataframe). After that, you transpose to get a column orientation :)